# Jquery + No conflict

Tags: jquery

I am sure similar version of this question is asked before but couldn't find answer for my specific issue.

1. I have an `html` which uses different `jquery` version + `colorbox` with some `css`.
2. I have to inject some code into this `html` which uses `jquery v1.9` and the code will not work with `jquery` version higher than 1.9 (this is strange but true).
3. So I am trying a way to isolate `jquery v1.9` with `noconflict` so that this injected piece of code (`html` elements + `javascript`) uses 1.9 and the main `html` continues to do whatever it was doing:

**html**

Existing js file using different version of `jquery`. Newly injected javascript(MYJAVASCRIPT) file using a different version of `jquery` than above
html

AS you can see in above `html`, I have file MYJAVASCRIPT which need to run with `jquery V1.9` and there are other JS files like `Main.js` which are using different version of `jquery`.

I want to isolate MYJAVASCRIPT to use `v1.9` without any changes to existing `html`.

Apologies if the question is not clear. I can provide more inputs if required.

Comment: Google about `jquery-migrate.js` and make use of it..

Comment: Your codes are not visible, insert them properly.And try jquery CDN of jquery version 1.9 or higher should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have two versions of jQuery, so call the `jq_1_9 = $.noConflict(true);` after your version of jquery is initialised, and use `jq_1_9` inplace of $ in your code.

Behind the scenes,

After all other versions of jquery initialize, the 1.9 version is initialized which overwrites the $ object with its own global scopes calling `$.noConflict(true)` will restore the global scopes to the original state. Hence the jquery v1.9 is lost so we assign that to a variable and use it wherever we need v1.9

eg.

```
<script src="other version"></script>
<script src="1.9 version"></script>
jq_1_9 = $.noconflict(true);

(function($){
   your functions go here;
})(jq_1_9);
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I am going to give it a shot and update. However similar stuff i tried earlier and it looks like, doing this way blocks some of the code from execution which is of other jquery version. If I assign different variables for each jquery version and use that would be fine but assigning variable for just one version didnt quite work well but as I said, i will give one more shot and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, if you have more than two versions you will have to assign variables for each version and pass it to different closures.